# Creating UTF8 language dictionary using g2p-seq2seq

Tags: cmusphinx

I am preparing a CMU sphinx data dictionary for new language.
I've made few hundreds tranliteration in ur.txt, and and training it by passing to g2p-seq2seq as mentioned in docs, its resulting in Accuracy:0 and Error:1.

The wordlist file is utf8 with urdu characters. http://pastebin.com/2rRXay9J
Just testing it first time, can anyone identify the issue in it or it is correct?

```
# g2p-seq2seq --train ur.txt --model ur-model3 --size 512 --max_steps 50 &
Preparing G2P data
Creating vocabularies in ur-model3
Creating vocabulary ur-model3/vocab.phoneme
Creating vocabulary ur-model3/vocab.grapheme
Reading development and training data.
Creating 2 layers of 512 units.
Created model with fresh parameters.
Training done.
Creating 2 layers of 512 units.
Reading model parameters from ur-model3
Beginning calculation word error rate (WER) on test sample.
Words: 14
Errors: 14
WER: 1.000
Accuracy: 0.000
```

Comment: You do not have enough data for training such a large model. Try with more data or set smaller model size (8 instead of 512).

Comment: Thanks, that was quick. Checking now.